# What is the right way to initialize an object that invoke an instance method of its mother?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, attributes, instance-methods

The question is as of the title. Say I have a simple example below:

```
class Vehicle
  attr_accessor :wheels
end

class Car < Vehicle
  def initialize
    self.wheels = 4
  end
end

class Truck < Vehicle
  def initialize
    @wheels = 16
  end
end
```

I am curious which way is considered correct or better to invoke
`wheels` writer method of mother `Vehicle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.wheels = 4` is more flexible because under the hood it is calling a setter method: `self.wheels=(4)`

So if you ever wanted to do something with the value before it is placed into `@wheels`, you could define that function:

```
def wheels=(val)
  # do something
  @wheels = new_val
end
```